# Unable to get home page using rails version 3.2.19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anybody help me to set the routes.rb file using rails version-3.2.19?I have created my home page as index.html.erb inside users folder.I have set " root :to => "users#index" " inside routes.rb file but while i typed "localhost:3000" on browser it is giving me the rails home page ,i am not getting my index page.Please help me to get index page directly by setting path inside routes.rb file.

Comment: so your home page is "users#index" what do you whish additinally?

Answer (score 1):

Delete index page from public folder